# Have my makefile show me compile errors?

Tags: c, makefile

```
exedarken: darken.c
    gcc -o exedarken darken.c

exeimagestats: imagestats.c
    gcc -o exeimagestats imagestats.c

exelighten: lighten.c
    gcc -o exelighten lighten.c

exerotate: rotate.c
    gcc -o exerotate rotate.c

exeflip: flip.c
    gcc -o exeflip flip.c

exematte: matte.c
    gcc -o exematte matte.c
```

Theres my makefile.  Is there a way for when I execute this makefile, I get to see the compile errors I get?

Comment: Don't you get the errors printed to console when you run make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, make prints the output of any command it executes, ie if there are compilation errors, they should be shown.

On an unrelated note: repeating yourself is bad; your makefile can be simplified to

```
executables := exedarken exeimagestats exelighten exerotate exeflip exematte

$(executables) : exe% : %.c
    gcc -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 2):

Write in console:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```